# Замена текста в текстовых редакторах с регулярными выражениями

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++, текстовый-редактор

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если в моем текстовом файле присутствуют, например, переменные следующего вида: `var0, var1, var2`.

Есть ли возможность как-нибудь через регулярные выражения осуществить их преобразование в `var[0], var[1], var[2]`?

Мне приходилось использовать регулярные выражения, но лишь с целью проверки, соответствует ли формат строки заданному формату. Просто мне кажется, что это можно как-то задействовать и для подобных операций в текстовых редакторах, поддерживающих регулярные выражения (в частности, Notepad++), но как - не знаю, к сожалению... Спасибо.

Comment: `var\\((?)\\)` -> `var[\1]` - что-то такое.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970405/notepad-regex-backreference-syntax-in-search-replace-1-or-1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Gm27sK/1

Comment: Найти: `(?<=[a-zA-Z])(\d+)(?=\s|$)`, заменить `[$1]`. Заменит все цифры идущие после любой буквы, после либо пробел, либо конец строки, на нужный формат

Comment: Спасибо Вам всем огромное! Будьте счастливы и здоровы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

найдите вхождения `var(\d+)` замените на `var[$1]`. Не забудьте ткнуть галку, что замена по регулярке

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!)